# Commutative operators

Tags: quantum-operation, matrix-representation, fidelity

I have got a 2-qubit circuit with the following instructions:

```
qc = QuantumCircuit(2,2)
qc.ry(2.1285844174659494, 0)
qc.u3(2.263106783376567, 0.3206834870221442, 0, 1)
qc.cx(1,0)
qc.u3(0.18291493410636106, -0.3915870470928269, 0.0, 0)
qc.cx(1,0)
qc.rz(0.17181884984660947, 0)
```

I guess I can reduce *cx* gates because *cx* commutes with *u3*. I check it via qiskit and numpy:

```
qc_ = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc_.u3(0.18291493410636106, -0.3915870470928269, 0.0, 1)
op1 = Operator(qc_.to_instruction()).data

qc_ = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc_.cx(1, 0)
op2 = Operator(qc_.to_instruction()).data
print((np.multiply(op1, op2) == np.multiply(op2, op1)).all())
```

The result is *True*.

However, the state fidelity of the original circuit and circuit without cx gates is 0.884. Do I understand correctly that I can remove the *cx* gates as far as *cx* and *u3* can be permuted?

Comment: Is np.multiply() not elementwise multiplication? If two operators commute we have $AB = BA$ where multiplication is matrix multiplication (not elementwise). This will probably explain the discrepancy you observe when you try to use commutation to simplify the circuit. For matrix multiplication in numpy you want np.matmul()

Comment: For the difference between `NumPy.multiply` and `NumPy.matmul` see here: https://mkang32.github.io/python/2020/08/30/numpy-matmul.html

Comment: you also can use `@` directly instead

Comment: I recommend you to learn the related necessary things with pennylane codebook. you can follow walkthrough from owen lockwood youtube channel.

Comment: also can use np.dot, detailed explanation: https://peps.python.org/pep-0465/

Comment: thank you all, guys! Should I remove the question? Afa I miunderstood the functions